# Prove or Disprove: $A\otimes B = 0 \implies A=0 \lor B=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

**Definitions**:

A function $f:V^k\to \mathbb R$ is called a $k$-tensor if it takes $k$ members of a vector space $V$, as the input, and is linear with respect to each of the input elements.
For example, $f(\alpha v_1,\dots,v_k)=\alpha f(v_1,\dots,v_k)$ and $f(v_1+v',\dots,v_k)=f(v_1,\dots,v_k)+f(v',\dots,v_k)$

$L^k(V)$ denotes the set of all $k$-tensors on the vector space $V$.

---

**Question:**

> Assume that $V$ is a vector space and for $A,B\in L^1(V)$ we have
>   $A\otimes B = 0$.  Can we conclude that $A=0$ or $B=0$?

Note 1: I know that if $x,y\in v$, Then the tensor product, $A \otimes B (x,y)=A(x)B(y)$ . Is this enough to conclude $A=0$ or $B=0$?
Note 2: $L^1(V)$ is actually the dual space of $V$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A \neq 0$ and $B \neq 0$, then $A(x) \neq 0$ and $B(y) \neq 0$ for some $x,y \in V$. It follows that $(A \otimes B) (x \otimes y) = A(x)B(y) \neq 0$, thus $A \otimes B \neq 0$.